# EntityFrameworkCore large Insert works in debug mode only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I used the insert code -'shown down' - tho insert sample data to MS SQL DB .
one of the tables -'shown down' - (last table to insert 'Records') has large insert it takes 5 minutes  in debug mode but when i try to start the project without debugging the table is empty in the DB and IIS-express is not throwing errors

The data has over 36,000 rows and over 40 columns

I **assumed** maybe because a "Connection Timeout"

so I tried to search for a solution and found two which none of them worked:

### 1.connection string

```
Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=1000;
```

### 2.Database.SetCommandTimeout

```
public MainContext()
    {
        //base.Database.SetCommandTimeout(1000);
    }
```

---

### Here the insert code

Modified from  https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs

---

```
    private static async Task AddOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        Func<TEntity, object> propertyToMatch, 
        IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        Exception exp = null;
        using (var scope = serviceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
            .CreateScope())
        using (var db = scope
            .ServiceProvider
            .GetService<MainContext>())
        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                    db.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exp = ex;
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        if (exp != null)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: How many records are involved out of interest? Your use of `existingData` would make this very slow if you have a reasonable amount of data. If that's the case, you might consider importing the records into a temp table and then updating your main table with a SQL query.

Comment: But you still perform an `Any` for each record, which is potentially O(n^2). You might want to at least create a dictionary / lookup to reduce that cost.

Comment: The data has over 36,000 rows and over 40 columns , the existingData is only used for update but not for insert
I use
db.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
db.SaveChanges();
transaction.Commit();

Comment: You should remove code that isn't relevant to your question. Try to keep your reproducible sample code small and concise.

Comment: thanks for the feedback  , I did remove irrelevant code.

Comment: Entity Framework is just not designed for this kind of bulk insert operation. I recommend looking at SqlBulkCopy instead.

Comment: I've filed issue [#6333](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6333) for us (the EF team) to investigate on our end.